# Create a html table that depends on the transaction table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to do it in a while loop but i don't know how to get the name with the transactions based on the sample table.

**transaction table** in a database

```
 ID   Name      Date of transaction   Amount
 1    James     01/01/2018            150
 2    James     03/02/2018            30
 3    John      03/03/2018            800
 4    John      04/08/2018            20 
 5    James     05/15/2018            2000
```

Above is my transaction table and i want data in below format

```
Name    1st Payment   2nd Payment     3rd Payment
James   150           30              2000
John    800           20
```

I only know how to show the database table, but i don't know how to add it here, like make it base on the name. Here's my sample code:

```
$sample = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM report");
while($samp = mysqli_fetch_array($sample)) {
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>".$samp['name']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$samp['transaction_date']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$samp['amount']."</td>";
echo"<tr>";
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? & also explain that (transaction table is your database table or file or array?)

Comment: the transaction table is my database table. I tried while loop but it only shows the whole transaction. @BilalAhmed

Comment: post your code to get the detail idea

Comment: I am only new to coding and that's what i come up so far @UpendraJoshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a suitable code on the basis of performance, my suggestion is you should optimize the query

But this code will resolve your issue.

```
$sample = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM report GROUP BY Name");
while($samp = mysqli_fetch_array($sample)) {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$samp['name']."</td>";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM report where name = '".$samp['name']."'");
    while($samp2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo"<td>".$samp2['amount']."</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to setup name at Your Databases, Then you date wise the payment. and u can condition apply order(01/01/2018 - 31/01/2018) In the middle Who payment this ,thay are  1st Payment ,as like 2nd Payment  and 3rd Payment  .

```html
<html>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$qry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FORM `example`");
$qry->execute();
$fetch_list = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($fetch_list AS $result_example){ 
?>
<tr>
<td><?php print $result_example['NAME']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $result_example['Date']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $result_example['Amount']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $result_example['NAME']; ?></td>
 
</tr>

<?php} // WHILE ?>
</tbody> 
</table>
</html>
```